# Derivative in both arguments of torch.nn.BCELoss()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, cross-entropy

When using a [`torch.nn.BCELoss()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html#torch.nn.BCELoss) on two arguments that are both results of some earlier computation, I get some curious error, which this question is about:

```
RuntimeError: the derivative for 'target' is not implemented
```

The MCVE is as follows:

```
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F

net1 = torch.nn.Linear(1,1)
net2 = torch.nn.Linear(1,1)
loss_fcn = torch.nn.BCELoss()

x = torch.zeros((1,1))

y = F.sigmoid(net1(x)) #make sure y is in range (0,1)
z = F.sigmoid(net2(y)) #make sure z is in range (0,1)

loss = loss_fcn(z, y) #works if we replace y with y.detach()

loss.backward()
```

It turns out if we call `.detach()` on `y` the error disappears. But this results in a different computation, now in the `.backward()`-pass, the gradients with respect to the second argument of the `BCELoss` will not be computed.

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong in this case? As far as I know all pytorch modules in `torch.nn` should support computing gradients. And this error message seems to tell me that the derivative is not implemented for `y`, which is somehow strange, as you *can* compute the gradient of `y`, but not of `y.detach()` which seems to be contradictory.

Comment: How about `loss = (loss_fcn(z, y.detach()) + loss_fcn(y, z.detach()))/2`?

Comment: @NagabhushanSN Note that this loss function is not symmetric with respect to the arguments, so this will not result in the desired loss.

Comment: you're right, it'll be different. But will it not serve your purpose? You need the network to update both `y` and `z` such that they come close to each other. The above loss function will achieve that right?

Comment: But then you could also use any other loss function or alternatively just manually implement the BCE loss:) When I asked this question I was really just curious about the behaviour of the built in `BCELoss()` function Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I misunderstood the error message. It is not `y` that doesn't allow the computation for gradients, it is `BCELoss()` that doesn't have the ability to compute gradients with respect to the second argument. A similar problem was discussed [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/runtimeerror-the-derivative-for-target-is-not-implemented-when-trying-to-backprop-through-kl/13362).

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem too. As far as I know, the second argument of `BCELoss(input, target)`,`target` should be a tensor without gradient attribute. It means that `target.requires_grad` should be False. But I don't know why.

Usually, the `target`(we can also call it `Ground Truth`) doesn't have a gradient attribute. But the `target`(`y` in your code) was calculated by `F.sigmoid(net1(x))`, which means the `target` (output of net1) has been a tensor with gradient attribute.

so, you should try:

> loss = loss_fcn(z, y.detach())

or:

> loss = loss_fcn(z, y.data)

maybe this?

```
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F

net1 = torch.nn.Linear(1,1)
net2 = torch.nn.Linear(1,1)
loss_fcn = torch.nn.BCELoss()

x = torch.zeros((1,1))

y = F.sigmoid(net1(x)) #make sure y is in range (0,1)
z = F.sigmoid(net2(y)) #make sure z is in range (0,1)

y.retain_grad()
a = y

loss = loss_fcn(z, a.detach()) #works if we replace y with y.detach()

loss.backward()

print(y.grad)
```

Comment: That is what I already did (see question) but it does not solve the problem I asked about. If you do this, then the gradients with respect to the second argument will *not* be computed, and this is exactly what I was asking to avoid.

Comment: I think we are talking about different problems, here my problem is still not solved: If we call `a.detach()` then `loss.backward()` will *not* compute any gradients of `loss` with respect to the parameters of `a`. (Note that the  parameters of `net1` will still have gradients, but only due to the path through the path of the first argument `z` of our loss, but not through the second argument.

Comment: To illustrate what I mean: Let `bce(x,y) = y * log(x) + (1-y) * log(1-x)`. Then the *actual* gradient would be `bce'(x,y) = [x' * (y / x - (1-y)/(1-x)), y' * log(x) - y' * log(1-x)]`. But if we use `y.detach()` then the optimizer will only use `bce'(x) = x' * (y / x - (1-y)/(1-x))`, but the second entry will be completely ignored. But that is the problem, I don't want the second entry to be ignored, I need that in the computation of my losses.